# WPF MVVM: ObservableValidator with Model in backing field

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

My Code looks a bit like the following:

```
public class MyModel {

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

}

public class MyViewModel: ObservableValidator {

    private mModelInstance;

    public MyViewModel(MyModel modelInstance){
        this.mModelInstance = modelInstance;
    }

    [MinLength(20)]
    public string MyProperty {
        get => mModelInstance.MyProperty;
        set => SetProperty(ref mModelInstance.MyProperty, value, validate = true); // This doesn't work because mModelInstance.MyProperty is a Property which cannot be passed as ref
    }
}
```

Now I see a few possible ways to do this, but am unsure which is best:

1. Move Validation and PropertyChanged to Model and introduce a private backing field for MyProperty in MyModel. I then expose ModelInstance as a Property in ViewModel. This allows me to use `SetProperty(ref mMyProperty, value, validate = true)` in the MyModel.MyProperty setter.
2. I can change MyModel.MyProperty to be a public field instead of a public property. However, this (from what I know) is a bad practice. Is this also bad in a POCO?
3. Instead of one call to `SetProperty`, I can do the following in the MyViewModel.MyProperty setter:

```
set {
    mModelInstance.MyProperty = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    ValidateProperty(value);
}
```

This works and my Model is unchanged (i.e. still has public properties, not fields). It is the approach I would have chosen, but the fact that I have 3 separate statements instead of the one provided by MVVM-Toolkit made me hesitate a bit.

Comment: Personally I'd just define all the fields I need in the VM and then copy them to an instance of the `MyModel` class in some handler method when the data is committed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience view model defines its own backing fields and also public method (e.g. Save()) to commit changes to model:

with more than one property it is very easy to create invalid combination of their values, and there is no telling how well model can handle it.

```
public class MyViewModel: ObservableValidator {

    private mModelInstance;

    public MyViewModel(MyModel modelInstance){
        this.mModelInstance = modelInstance;
    }

    private string _myProperty;
    [MinLength(20)]
    public string MyProperty {
        get => _myProperty;
        set => SetProperty(ref _myProperty, value, validate = true);
    }

    public void Save() {
        mModelInstance.MyProperty = _myProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can and should take it one step further and introduce a type to move data between model and view model to ensure model's data integrity. Save an object instead of explicitly assigning value to properties of the model. This eliminates the need that the view model has to know about model implementation details. For example, you would save a `User` object instead of explicitly assigning the view model's username value to a `Model.Username` property and a user mail address to a `Model.MailAddress` property etc. So, `MyModel` would expose a `MyModel.Save(User):void` method for this purpose.